# What was the difference between the Sykes Picot and League of Nations Mandate?

Tags: world-war-one, middle-east, ottoman-empire

I can't really understand.  I read history that says the [Sykes-Picot Agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sykes%E2%80%93Picot_Agreement) was this secret agreement and it is why the Middle East is the way it is today.

But then there's this other [League of Nations mandate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/League_of_Nations_mandate) system.  Mandate for Iraq, Syria etc...

So which agreement actually drew these borders?  And what was the Middle East doing for the two years after the war and before the mandate system? Were they occupied by Britain and France?

Comment: At a very, very, bare minimum: at least search this site for your key words before posting a (many times) duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

[Sykes-Picot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sykes%E2%80%93Picot_Agreement) is a 1916 secret agreement to define spheres of influence.

> a 1916 secret treaty between the United Kingdom and France, with assent from the Russian Empire and the Kingdom of Italy, to define their mutually agreed spheres of influence and control in an eventual partition of the Ottoman Empire.

[League of Nations Mandate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/League_of_Nations_mandate)

> a legal status for certain territories transferred from the control of one country to another following World War I, or the legal instruments that contained the internationally agreed-upon terms for administering the territory on behalf of the League of Nations. These were of the nature of both a treaty and a constitution, which contained minority rights clauses that provided for the rights of petition and adjudication by the Permanent Court of International Justice.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sykes%E2%80%93Picot_Agreement)

The first is secret; the second public. The first defines spheres of influence, the second defines countries.

Can you further amplify what is confusing? I'm not challenging the confusion, just trying to figure out precisely where the confusion lies.

If the question is actually about the boundaries of a specific country, can you specify which country?